# Can I use the PGOPTIONS environment variable for a ruby on rails rails postgresql session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, github-actions

I'd like to make rails configure it's PostgreSQL client sessions with the [PGOPTIONS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#id-1.6.7.4.5) environment variable. I need this to configure the [pg_trgm GUC parameter word_similarity_threshold](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.7).

I'd prefer to configure this parameter in this way, because I need this for use with a postgres service in github actions where I can only configure the postgres docker container with environment variables, so If there's a way to set this parameter serverside with env variables, I'd also be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can just set the PGOPTIONS environment variable for your ruby on rails process, and that will be passed on to any postgres connections it makes.

So we ended up with the following environment variable for our ruby process:

```
env:
   PGOPTIONS: "-c pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold=0.2"
```